# Open links in the nearby window (no splits)

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I have a 24 inch display and usually have 2 windows open:

```
|-------+----------------|
| Links | Working window |
| (30%) | (70%)          |
|       |                |
|-------+----------------|
```

When I click a link, it splits the working window into 2 parts:

```
|-------+---------+-------------|
| Links | Working | Linked file |
| (30%) | window  | (35%)       |
|       | (35%)   |             |
|-------+---------+-------------|
```

This makes work very uncomfortable. Is it possible to tell Emacs to open the linked content in the working window?

```
|-------+-------------|
| Links | Linked file |
| (30%) | (70%)       |
|       |             |
|-------+-------------|
```

In my case `org-open-at-point` is called.

Comment: Does it happen if you start with `emacs -Q`? If not, something in your init file causes this: bisect it to find out what. FWIW, I cannot reproduce it with my normal init file or with `emacs -Q`, so I suspect that you will find the same thing.